# Doing interrupt chaining assignment

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, interrupt-handling

As the title says I'm trying to do the interrut chaining. What I'm looking for is that when the Timer Interrupt (IRQ 0) is called, and the interrupt handler (ISR) finishes it executes my code. I'm trying to do it on Assembly, C or any language that allows me to do that. I found an example on this [page](http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH17/CH17-4.html#HEADING4-1) but it doesn't work on TASM. Could you help me with this, or where I can find information about this? Thank you. :D

Comment: Chained interrupt handling is highly dependent on the working environment (OS, chip, etc...), and was never the most common way to program. You should probably be more specific about what kind of system you are working on, and even then patience might be in order.

Comment: I'm working on Windows XP over VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not using it anymore, but just wanted to play again with probably the assembler I gave my first steps in assembly:

```
.186
.MODEL TINY, C

.code
ORG 100h

Entry:
; Install handler
   push   ds
   xor    cx, cx
   mov    ds, cx
   mov    ax, ds:[8*4]
   mov    dx, ds:[8*4+2]
   cli
   mov    ds:[8*4], OFFSET InterruptHandler
   mov    ds:[8*4+2], cs
   pop    ds
   mov    word ptr [OldIntVect], ax
   mov    word ptr [OldIntVect+2], dx
   sti

; Wait for the user to press a key. In the meantime you should see lots of wildcards!
   xor   ax, ax
   int   16h

; Restore original handler
   mov    ax, word ptr [OldIntVect]
   mov    dx, word ptr [OldIntVect+2]
   push   ds
   xor    cx, cx
   mov    ds, cx
   cli
   mov    ds:[8*4], ax
   mov    ds:[8*4+2], dx
   sti
   pop    ds

; Exit to DOS
   int   20h

PROC MyHandler

   mov   ah, 0Eh
   mov   al, '*'
   int   10h
   ret
ENDP


InterruptHandler:
   pushf
   call  cs:[OldIntVect]
   cmp   [busy], 0
   jne   ExitHandler ; If jumps then the timer was faster than the time it takes for MyHandler to complete

   mov   cs:[busy], 1
   pusha
   call  MyHandler ; Other options are using a pointer to function or just inlining the code here.
   popa
   mov   cs:[busy], 0

ExitHandler:
   iret

OldIntVect dd ?
busy       db ?

END Entry
```

Tested under WinXP (32-bit):

```
>tasm timer.asm
Turbo Assembler  Version 1.01  Copyright (c) 1988, 1989 Borland International

Assembling file:   TIMER.ASM
Error messages:    None
Warning messages:  None
Remaining memory:  481k


>tlink /t timer.obj
Turbo Link  Version 3.0 Copyright (c) 1987, 1990 Borland International

>timer
***************************
```

But this of course is only valid for a DOS environment (DOSBox, Windows 32-bit versions, etc.) and with some tweaks for a bootloader at most.

Anyway, thanks for the beautiful time you just gave me reviving all this :P

Comment: Amazing how you did it! Thank you! :D